# How to detect value variables prior to reshape wide to long?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Consider the below df. Notice how the user Paul has two colors vs his name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names' :['Stacey', 'John', 'Paul'],
                  'blue':['blue',np.nan, np.nan],
                  'yellow':[np.nan, 'yellow', np.nan],
                  'green': [np.nan, np.nan, 'green'],
                   'purple':[np.nan, np.nan, 'purple' ]
                 })
print(df)


 names    blue  yellow   green   purple
0  Stacey  blue     NaN    NaN     NaN
1    John   NaN  yellow    NaN     NaN
2    Paul   NaN     NaN  green  purple
```

If I am to reshape this df from wide to long, with `pd.melt`, I will expect the id 'Paul' entry to be duplicated.

```
df.melt(id_vars='names',
        value_vars = ['blue','yellow','green','purple'],
        value_name = 'color').dropna().drop('variable', axis=1))

      names   color
0   Stacey    blue
4     John  yellow
8     Paul   green
11    Paul  purple
```

How would one isolate/detect the repeated entries in the inital df so the output would be?:

```
    names    blue  yellow   green   purple
 2    Paul   NaN     NaN    green   purple
```

Thank you in advance:

pandas 0.23.4

python 3.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for coun with exclude missing values with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df[['blue','yellow','green','purple']].count(axis=1) > 1]
print (df)
  names blue yellow  green  purple
2  Paul  NaN    NaN  green  purple
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[['blue','yellow','green','purple']].count(axis=1))
0    1
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks again @jezrael! exactly what I required.